# Ansible, task, playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Есть задача скопировать на хосты папку с файлами и сделать этим скопированным файлам аналог chmod +x

```
---
  - host: ABC
    become: True
    become_method: su
    gather_facts: su

    task:
         - name: Copy folder to host
           copy:
               src: /home/temp/my_folder
               dest: /home/work_folder
         - name: Change files1 to exec
           file: dest=/home/work_folder/file1.sh mode=a+x
         - name: Change files2 to exec
           file: dest=/home/work_folder/file2.sh mode=a+x
```

и всё типа такого

но при выполнении playbook возникает ошибка:
первый файл становиться исполняемым, а дальше ошибка:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false? "msg": "file (/home/work_folder/file2.sh) is absent, cannot continue", "path": "/home/work_folder/file2.sh"}

почему file2.sh absent, он существует если зайти на хост

в чём проблема?

Спасибо!

и ещё вопрос: почему playbook надо запускать с ключём (-К) и вводить root пароль, иначе ошибка:

> FAILED! => "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:"

Comment: Ответ на первую часть вопроса на нашёл сам, мною были допущены ошибки в именах файлов и поэтому возникала ошибка.
А вот вопрос с ключом (-К) так и не решился, как можно запускать безного и без ввода root-пароля
Спасибо!

Comment: В смысле без ввода пароля? Для суперпользователя есть штука `become: yes`.

Comment: не помогает 
только если стоит ключ -К при запуске PlayBook, система спросить root пароль и начнет выполнять сценарий